# how get a initial image back when mouse is taken away after hovering using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hover").hover(function(event){
        var imgSrc = $(event.currentTarget).find('img').attr("src");
        $(".main-image img").attr("src", imgSrc);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hover ").onmouseleave(function(event){
        var imgSrc = $(event.currentTarget).find('.p img').attr("src");
        $(".main-image img").attr("src", imgSrc);
        alert("imgSrc");
    });
});
```

i have return a above code for hovering on a image and showing that same image in another block but what i want is when i remove my mouse away from hovering image i want original image in tht block

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hover').hover(function(){
    var imgSrc = $(event.currentTarget).find('img').attr("src");
    $(".main-image img").attr("src", imgSrc);
},
function(){
    $(".main-image img").attr("src", "yourdefaultsrc.png");
    alert("imgSrc");
});
```

Comment: it is still not working all what i want is to show the original image in a block after the hovering effect is done

Comment: so place src you need, by not founding something in '.p img', but by the way like this:
`$('.main-image img').attr('src', '/img/image.png');`